# Ionic - file upload works just on some devices

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to do a file upload to a PHP script.

**Problem**: On a `Samsung Galaxy S7`, the code is working fine. Unfortunately on a `Lenovo Phab 2 Pro` and a `Nexus 5X` it does not work but runs the code inside the app without any error.

On the server side I have noticed that the App on the `Samsung Galaxy S7` is sending the files correctly whereas `Lenovo Phab 2 Pro` and a `Nexus 5X` just send the file names.

`Samsung Galaxy S7`:

```
 upload response: Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1506589380396.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDKfBfF
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1032669
        )

)
Upload and move success
```

`Lenovo Phab 2 Pro` and `Nexus 5X`:

```
upload response: uploads/1506589002819.jpgArray
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1506589002819.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

I have used the code of that [tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/) to do a file upload to a server. But it does not seem to be a matter of the code because another [tutorial](https://golb.hplar.ch/p/Uploading-pictures-from-Ionic-2-to-Spring-Boot) ends up with the same result.

On a `Samsung Galaxy S7`, the code is working fine. Unfortunately on a `Lenovo Phab 2 Pro` and a `Nexus 5X` it does not work but runs the code without any error.  It seems like they are not even sending a file to the server.
On both devices, I can display the images in the app itself and I can search for them within a file browser app like [TotalCommand](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander&hl=en).

**Question**: What could be the problem on the `Lenovo Phab 2 Pro` and a `Nexus 5X`? Note that all permissions are granted to the app (Memory, GPS, Phone).

This is my code:

```
   @IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-eventlist',
  templateUrl: 'eventlist.html',
})
export class EventlistPage {
  private TAG = "EventlistPage ";

  photoPage = PhotoPage;
  eventPage = EventPage;

  events: Event[];

  loading:Loading;
  public error: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly http: Http,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public eventtrackerProvider: EventtrackerProvider,
    //private transfer: FileTransfer,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private file: File,
    private loadingController: LoadingController,
    private platform: Platform,
    // instanciate the NetworkConnectionProvider here to make it available in the whole application
    network: NetworkConnectionProvider) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        //this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
      });
  }

  async ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.TAG + "ionViewDidLoad");

    try {
      let data = await this.eventtrackerProvider.getEvents()
      this.events = data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(this.TAG  + err.message);
    }
  }

  async uploadImagesToServer(){
    await this.checkForNotUploadedImages();
  }

  async checkForNotUploadedImages() {

    let noPicsForUploadAvailable: Boolean;
    noPicsForUploadAvailable = true;

    this.loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      content: 'Lade hoch...',
    });
    this.loading.present();

    try {
      for(let event of this.events) {
        for(let image of event.images){
          if(image.uploadedToServer == false) {

            // upload the image to server

            this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(image.filePath + image.fileName)
              .then(entry => (<FileEntry>entry).file(file => this.readFile(file)))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));

            noPicsForUploadAvailable = false;

          }
        }
        await this.eventtrackerProvider.updateEvent(event);
      }

    } catch(err) {
      console.log(this.TAG + err.message);
      this.presentAlert(this.TAG + err.message);
    }

    await this.loading.dismiss();
    if(noPicsForUploadAvailable){
      await this.presentAlert("Es gibt aktuell keine Bilder zum Hochladen.")
    } else {
      await this.presentAlert("FileTransfer erfolgreich");
    }
  }

  private readFile(file: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      const imgBlob = new Blob([reader.result], {type: file.type});
      formData.append('file', imgBlob, file.name);
      this.postData(formData);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

  private postData(formData: FormData) {
    this.http.post("http://192.168.178.111/upload.php", formData)
      .catch((e) => this.handleError(e))
      .map(response => console.log("upload response: " + response.text()))
      .finally(() => this.loading.dismiss())
      .subscribe(ok => this.presentAlert("ok"));
  }

  presentAlert(message: string){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Alert',
      subTitle: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
   let errMsg: string;
   if (error instanceof Response) {
     const body = error.json() || '';
     const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
     errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
   } else {
     errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
   }
   this.error = errMsg;
   return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**Question**: Is that problem caused by denied permissions on the file systems? That would not make any sense to me because before the app was able to create and display the image without any problem. What else could be wrong here?